# How to define string that contains the symbols double and single quote at the same time, in Powerhsell?

Tags: string, powershell

I need to put the following text format into a variable

> "Sometext":"more text";'still text

However, because the text has double and single quotes, I can't put it in a string. I've tried using @''@, and @""@ but it's not working.
Sidenote: I can't edit the text because it's originated automatically
What can I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "I've tried using @''@, and @""@ but it's not working" please show us your previous attempts and describe what happens (feel free to post any error messages that occur)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a literal, you can use a [here string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/):

```
$variable = @"
"Sometext":"more text";'still text
"@
```

(Note that the final `"@` has to be on a separate line, at the very beginning of that line.)

Answer (score 0):

To build strings with complex quotations, consider [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting). Save the quotes in a variable and use formatting placeholders to insert them. Like so,

```
$squote = "'"
$dquote = '"
$myString = "{0}Sometext{0}:{0}more text{0};{1}still text" -f $dquote, $squote
$myString
"Sometext":"more text";'still text
```